# Modal window for all div's with the same class

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to create a modal window for all div's with the same class located in an associative array from php

Using an associative array, I displayed product cards, when I click on "More details" I want to get a modal window with a description of the product

Please help me, I'm just starting to learn programming languages, maybe my code is flawed, I'm sorry.

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="name"><?php echo $fish['name']; ?></div>
  <div class="price"><?php echo $fish['price']; ?></div>
  <button id="myBtn" class="button-intro">Подробнее</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="img-wrap"><img src="<?php echo $fish['img']; ?>"alt=""></div>
         <div class="wrapper-block">
             <div class="name-close">
                 <div class="name-block"><?php echo $fish['name']; ?></div>
                 <button id="close" class="btn-close">&times;</button>
             </div>
             <div class="description-shelf">
                 <div class="description-block"><p>Описание</p></div>
                 <div class="shelf-block"><p>Срок годности:<?php echo $fish['shelf']; ?></p></div>
             </div>
             <div class="description"><p><?php echo $fish['description']; ?></p></div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

const mod = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
const but = document.querySelectorAll('.button-intro');
const bclose = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-close');
but.onclick = () => {
    mod.style.display = "block";
}
bclose.onclick = () => {
    mod.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == mod) {
        mod.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

There are 6 products in my array, but when I click on the button, the function only works on one product

Comment: `but` and `bclose` are _lists_ of buttons. You would need to loop through them and assign the click listener to each one separately. Likewise `mod` is a _list_ of modals, so you can't set the `style` of a list.

Comment: If this is using Bootstrap, bootstrap provides ways for you to achieve opening and closing your modals anyway without using JavaScript. Check the documentation on modals for your bootstrap version. If you give each modal a unique `id` (which it needs anyway - you can't have multiple identical `id`s in a HTML document, it's not valid or logical) then each of your buttons can directly target the associated modal by its ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your logic is that `querySelectorAll()` returns a *Collection* of entities, not a single one. You therefore need to loop over them all and attach the event handlers individually.

Also, there's a couple of other things you can do to improve the quality of your code:

- Use `addEventListener()` instead of `onclick`. The latter is a property which can easily be overwritten and cause unexpected issues.
- Remove `id` attributes from repeated content created in a loop. `id` must be unique.
- You can relate the buttons to their respective modals by using DOM traversal methods such as `closest()` and `querySelector()`. This negates the need to track each items index in the event handlers.
- Use a CSS class to update the state of elements where possible.

Here's a working example with the above amendments made:

```js
const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
const introButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.button-intro');
const modalCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-close');

introButtons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.target.closest('.card').querySelector('.modal').classList.add('show');
  });
});

modalCloseButtons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.closest('.modal').classList.remove('show'));
});

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (event.target.closest('.modal') == null) {
    modals.forEach(modal => modal.classList.remove('show'));
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #CCC;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}
.modal.show {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="name">
    Fish name 1
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    Fish price 1
  </div>
  <button class="button-intro">Подробнее</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="img-wrap"><img src="<?php echo $fish['img']; ?>" alt=""></div>
      <div class="wrapper-block">
        <div class="name-close">
          <div class="name-block">
            Fish name 1
          </div>
          <button class="btn-close">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="description-shelf">
          <div class="description-block">
            <p>Описание</p>
          </div>
          <div class="shelf-block">
            <p>Срок годности:
              Fish shelf 1
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <p>
            Fish description 1
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="name">
    Fish name 2
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    Fish price 2
  </div>
  <button class="button-intro">Подробнее</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="img-wrap"><img src="<?php echo $fish['img']; ?>" alt=""></div>
      <div class="wrapper-block">
        <div class="name-close">
          <div class="name-block">
            Fish name 2
          </div>
          <button class="btn-close">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="description-shelf">
          <div class="description-block">
            <p>Описание</p>
          </div>
          <div class="shelf-block">
            <p>Срок годности:
              Fish shelf 2
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <p>
            Fish description 2
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="name">
    Fish name 3
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    Fish price 3
  </div>
  <button class="button-intro">Подробнее</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="img-wrap"><img src="<?php echo $fish['img']; ?>" alt=""></div>
      <div class="wrapper-block">
        <div class="name-close">
          <div class="name-block">
            Fish name 3
          </div>
          <button class="btn-close">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="description-shelf">
          <div class="description-block">
            <p>Описание</p>
          </div>
          <div class="shelf-block">
            <p>Срок годности:
              Fish shelf 3
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <p>
            Fish description 3
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```